# Android buttons to match up on screen no matter what device

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am starting to write my first android application and I am adding some buttons.

I want a banner button top and bottom which I have managed and then 4 buttons in the middle of equal size filling the remaining space.

Is there any way of doing this without just trial and erroring the size and so that it works on any device?

[image: Current App Layout]

Here is my code -

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="650px"
        android:layout_height="1000px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="650px"
        android:layout_height="1000px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="650px"
        android:layout_height="1000px"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="650px"
        android:layout_height="1000px"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
        android:id="@+id/button8" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Square buttons? Most devices are taller than are wide, so you'll get rectangles in most cases, but you can preview all screen sizes at once in Android Studio. No need to run an emulator

Comment: Hi, sorry yes rectangles I mean. Good to know! The emulator kills my laptop.

Comment: RelativeLayout shouldn't be what you want, then. LinearLayout for the parent, vertical 3 rows, add weight to those rows for sizing, then the middle row is a GridLayout of 4 buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using any libraries you can achieve this. The space between the top and buttom buttons will be splited equally to 4(It won't be squares always depending on the screen size)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@id/button6">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 3"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, This works perfectly. If I want to make the top and bottom banner buttons slightly larger what would I need to change?

Comment: @benjano just change the height attribute to some dp replacing wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that doesn't have nested layout_weight attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/top_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_button"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_button"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        android:columnCount="2">
        <Button
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```